# window.resize fail when using Modernizr and Zepto

Tags: javascript, resize, window, modernizr, zepto

I'm having a problem with resizing an element using JavaScript and the Zepto library. When the page loads the element gets the window width and height just fine. I have also tested my window.resize with an alert() and that works fine too. My problems occurs when I try and resize the element as the window changes size. Here is my JavaScript which is loaded through Modernizr:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);

    var navConfig = 
    {
        winWidth        : $(window).width(),
        winHeight       : $(window).height(),
        primaryNav      : $('#primaryNav'),
        openPrimaryNav  : $('#openPrimaryNav'),
        closePrimaryNav : $('#closePrimaryNav')
    }

    function sizePrimaryNavigation()
    {
        navConfig.primaryNav.css(
        {
            'height'    : navConfig.winHeight - 5,
            'width'     : navConfig.winWidth - 20
        });
    }

    function primaryNavigation()
    {   
        navConfig.openPrimaryNav.bind('click', function()
        {
            navConfig.primaryNav.addClass('open');
        });

        navConfig.closePrimaryNav.bind('click', function()
        {
            navConfig.primaryNav.removeClass('open');
        }); 
    }

    sizePrimaryNavigation();

    primaryNavigation();

    window.onresize = sizePrimaryNavigation;
});
```

I have also set up a working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/nicklansdell/DWbNS/2/ Click the menu button on the demo for the element I am trying to resize.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried binding to the onresize event? Like $(window).bind('onresize', function(event){});

Comment: Hi. Yes I have tried that too with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked, write the function like this, it will work.
demo is here

http://jsfiddle.net/DWbNS/7/

http://jsfiddle.net/DWbNS/9/

and by the way,zepto doc says "bind" is "Deprecated, use on instead."

```
function sizePrimaryNavigation()
{
    navConfig.primaryNav.css(
    {
        'height'     : win.width() - 5,
        'width'        : win.height() - 20
    });

}
$(window).resize(sizePrimaryNavigation);
// window.onresize = sizePrimaryNavigation;
// will work too
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the `onresize` property to a **jQuery object** (`$(window)`). You MUST assign it to `window.onresize` instead.

Comment: Kolink thanks for the reply I have updated my code and it still does not work. I have reflected the changes in the example above and on the demo. Also I am not using jQuery, I am using Zepto

Comment: Instead of using the `function foo()` syntax, try `var foo = function()` instead.

Comment: No good I'm afraid. On the fiddle if you take out the initial call to sizePrimaryNavigation() open the menu then resize the window you will see it does execute but only once. As far as I'm aware it should carry on resizing indefinitely.

Comment: Move the `navConfig` stuff inside the `sizePrimaryNavigation()` function. It needs to be recalculated based on updated window size.

Comment: Again no good. I have used this exact pattern before with jQuery and its worked no problem. I don't understand it.