# CSS or Javascript: How to fit two portrait images side by side in a container with fluid width?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have a flexible `.container` with `width:100%`. I want to fit two portrait images (with varying widths) side by side into this `.container``

```
<div class="container">
       <p>Some Text</p>
       <img src="this-is-a-landscape-image.jpg" alt="test"/>
       <p> Some Text again</p>
       <img class="portait" src="this-is-a-portrait-image.jpg" alt="test"/>
       <img class="portrait" src="this-is-a-portrait-image.jpg" alt="test"/>
</div>
```

**The problem I have:**
I'm working on a responsive-layout where this `.container` is flexible - `width:100%`. 
However I want to be able to fit two images (that have the class `.portrait`) into this container side by side.

[image]

As you can see in this sample image, the two `.portrait` images are not necessarily the same width? I want them to be the same height, but the width should be dynamic (if they don't have the same ratio)

Is this somehow possible with pure css (maybe flexbox)? Or a little JS?

The contents are filled dynamically via a CMS, so that's the reason I can't hardcode it.

Any creative or helpful ideas?

Comment: `max-width: 100%` on the images?

Comment: float: left dont solve your problem?

Comment: If you're looking to keep the portrait images displaying side by side no matter the resolution, flexbox won't help you unless you can insert an extra tag to contain those images.  Sorry to disappoint:  http://jsfiddle.net/HLPsw/1/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a fully dynamic solution in pure css (though I would love to be proven wrong!)

I wrote a quick jQuery solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/d2gSK/2/
You can play with the image sizes, the window size, and the width of the gutter, and your height should stay the same for both images, while the width is set to proportion.

The javascript looks like this:

```
    // put it in a function so you can easily reuse it elsewhere
    function fitImages(img1, img2, gutter) {
        // turn your images into jQuery objects (so we can use .width() )
        var $img1 = $(img1);
        var $img2 = $(img2);
        // calculate the aspect ratio to maintain proportions
        var ratio1 = $img1.width() / $img1.height();
        var ratio2 = $img2.width() / $img2.height();
        // get the target width of the two images combined, taking the gutter into account
        var targetWidth = $img1.parent().width() - gutter;

        // calculate the new width of each image
        var width1 = targetWidth / (ratio1+ratio2) * ratio1;
        var width2 = targetWidth / (ratio1+ratio2) * ratio2;

        // set width, and height in proportion
        $img1.width(width1);
        $img1.height(width1 / ratio1);
        $img2.width(width2);
        $img2.height(width2 / ratio2);

        // add the gutter
        $img1.css('paddingRight', gutter + 'px');

    }

    //when the DOM is ready
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // cache the image container
        var $wrapper = $('.portrait-wrapper');
        // set the image sizes on load
        fitImages($wrapper.children().get(0), $wrapper.children().get(1), 20);

        // recalculate the image sizes on resize of the window
        $(window).resize(function() {
            fitImages($wrapper.children().get(0), $wrapper.children().get(1), 20);
        });
    });
```

I put the explanation inside the code. Feel free to ask if you want me to explain further.

Note that i put a wrapper around your images, and gave the images a `display: block` and a `float:left`, which is required to make this work!

Comment: Thank you, this function would probably work for me! However I need to make it work with "Zepto.js" and not jQuery. Any ideas why this wouldn't properly work with Zepto. I can't see any method that isn't supported by Zepto!?

Comment: To be honest I had never heard of Zepto until now. A quick google learned me that it is sort of a lightweight version of jquery, and a having a quick look at the API doc I don't think I used any unsupported functions. Why don't you just give it a try...

Comment: I just tried to switch to framework to Zepto on jsfiddle and it seems to work fine (on my iPad, not able to test the resize here)

Comment: I had a quick look and the little I can find point in the direction of a bug in Zepto. You are definitly not the only one with this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822589/window-resize-fail-when-using-modernizr-and-zepto Perhaps you should consider working with jQuery anyway, as long as you load it from something like ajax.googleapis.com most users will have it in cache anyway, so the size should not be an issue, and you will support the poor IE users as well

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
  <div class="container">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <img src="this-is-a-landscape-image.jpg" alt="test"/>
    <p> Some Text again</p>
    <div class="portraits">
      <img style="float:left;" class="portait" src="this-is-a-portrait-image.jpg" alt="test"/>
      <img style="float:right;" class="portrait" src="this-is-a-portrait-image.jpg" alt="test"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You should probably make the .container overflow:hidden to grow with the content.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Float on them so they get out of the "normal flow", or you could even use position absolute, if the text between the top image and them stays the same at all times...

For the width: you can simply make their width in % as well so you can say give the first one 80% and the second 20% using pseudo classes...

another possibility would be that you make different hard coded css's where you can easily define at what page width you want to use what css, for example something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   .portrait:first {
       width: 85px;
   }

   .portrait:last {
       width: 105px;
   }
}
```

and so on for every step on window size.

I Hope that helps :D